# Magento 2 graphql file upload not working

Tags: magento2, graphql

I am using this schema to file upload:

```
mutation{
     uploadImg (file: Upload!): File @resolver(class: "\\Test\\Cgraphql\\Model\\Resolver\\UpImg") @doc(description:"Upload img")
}
```

But getting error:

> Type \"Upload\" not found in document.\n\nException #0
>   (GraphQL\Error\Error): Type \"Upload\" not found in
>   document.\n#1
>   GraphQL\Utils\ASTDefinitionBuilder->internalBuildType('Upload',

Please let me know how can we upload image in graphql.

Comment: just pass the String instead of upload and do your upload script in you resolver.

Comment: but then it gives error Request content type must be application/json

Comment: how to resolve it. have you done it before?

Comment: explain your scope little bit more please, whether can help you in this?

Comment: I want to use image upload in magento 2 graphql. can you please provide its correct schema example of mutation file upload

Comment: please let me know if you have done it

Comment: we should use type String with file type base64 encode for that

Answer (score 0):

You see this error because you should describe new input type which called "Upload".
Your schema says:
There is mutation called "uploadImg". It has one required parameter called "file". Input type of data for "file" should be "Upload" (not "String", not "Int", but "Upload"). And this mutation returns data with type "File".
So, Magento can't find any declaration for input "Upload". For example, see "createCustomer" mutation and input "CustomerInput"